# Drawing Blob edges that are on sketch edge in Processing

Tags: java, processing, detection, edge-detection, edges

I've been working in Processing with the [blobDetection library](http://www.v3ga.net/processing/BlobDetection/index-page-documentation.html), making contour maps from heightmaps.
I am now exporting each layer as SVGs for laser cutting but blobs that are on the edge of the sketch are not complete, the edge vertices are not drawn.

Here is a simplified example:

1. The image I start with, white areas will become blobs

[image]

2. The SVG output, missing the edges

[image]

```
import processing.svg.*;
import blobDetection.*;
import peasy.*;
import processing.pdf.*;
PeasyCam cam;

PImage img;

float levels = 10;

BlobDetection[] contours = new BlobDetection[int(levels)];

//Creating array to store the blob objects
ArrayList<Ring> rings = new ArrayList<Ring>();

void setup() {

  size(480, 360, P3D);
  surface.setResizable(true);

  img = loadImage("maptest2.jpg");
  surface.setSize(img.width, img.height);

  cam = new PeasyCam(this, img.width, img.height, 0, 1500);
  colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100);

  for (int i=0; i<levels; i++) {
    contours[i] = new BlobDetection(img.width, img.height);
    contours[i].setThreshold(i/levels);
    contours[i].computeBlobs(img.pixels);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < rings.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("id: " + rings.get(i).getId());
    System.out.println("lvl: " + rings.get(i).getLvl());
    System.out.println("x: " + rings.get(i).getX());
    System.out.println("y: " + rings.get(i).getY());
    System.out.println();
  }

  noLoop();
}


void draw() {

  for (int i=0; i<levels; i++) {  

    beginRecord(SVG, "level-"+i+".svg");

    drawContours(i);
    println("drew level " + i);

    println("saved as: level-"+i+".svg");
    endRecord();
    println();

    if(i == levels-1){
      println("finished");
    }

  }

  System.out.println("Number of blobs (rings.size()): " + rings.size());
   println();

   for (int i = 0; i < rings.size(); i++){
   System.out.println("id: " + rings.get(i).getId());
   System.out.println("lvl: " + rings.get(i).getLvl());
   System.out.println("x: " + rings.get(i).getX());
   System.out.println("y: " + rings.get(i).getY());
   System.out.println();
   }

}

void drawContours(int i) {
  Blob b;
  EdgeVertex eA, eB;
  for (int n=0; n<contours[i].getBlobNb(); n++) {
    b=contours[i].getBlob(n);

    //Condition for drawing only blobs bigger than 5% of width and 5% of height
    if(b.w*width>.05*width && b.h*height>.05*height){

      if (b!=null) {
        stroke(250, 75, 90);

        for (int m=0; m<b.getEdgeNb(); m++) {
          eA = b.getEdgeVertexA(m);
          eB = b.getEdgeVertexB(m);

          //This part draws the blobs.

          if (eA !=null && eB !=null)
           line(
           eA.x*img.width, eA.y*img.height, 
           eB.x*img.width, eB.y*img.height 
           );

           println("eA.x: " + eA.x);
           println("eA.y: " + eA.y);
           println("eB.x: " + eB.x);
           println("eB.y: " + eB.y);
           println();

           ////////////
           //Here are my various attempts at drawing these rogue edges!
           //I commented them out

           /*      
           //Checking if vertex has a point at x=0
           if (b.getEdgeVertexA(m).x == 0 && b.getEdgeVertexB(b.getEdgeNb()).x == 0){


                 line(  b.getEdgeVertexA(0).x*img.width, b.getEdgeVertexA(0).y*img.height, 
                        b.getEdgeVertexA(m).x*img.width, b.getEdgeVertexA(m).y*img.height   );

                 println("////");
                 println("x making line (scaled 0-1): ");
                 //println(eA.x, eA.y, eB.x, eB.y);
                 println(  b.getEdgeVertexA(0).x, b.getEdgeVertexA(0).y, 
                           b.getEdgeVertexA(m).x, b.getEdgeVertexA(m).y   );

                 println("////");
           }

           //Checking if vertex has a point at y=0
           if (b.getEdgeVertexA(m).y == 0 && b.getEdgeVertexB(b.getEdgeNb()).y == 0){

             line(  b.getEdgeVertexA(0).x*img.width, b.getEdgeVertexA(0).y*img.height, 
                    b.getEdgeVertexA(m).x*img.width, b.getEdgeVertexA(m).y*img.height   );

                 println("////");
                 println("y making line (scaled 0-1): ");
                 //println(eA.x, eA.y, eB.x, eB.y);
                 println(  b.getEdgeVertexA(0).x, b.getEdgeVertexA(0).y, 
                           b.getEdgeVertexA(m).x, b.getEdgeVertexA(m).y   );

                 println("////");

           }

           if (b.getEdgeVertexA(m).x == 0 && b.getEdgeVertexB(b.getEdgeNb()).y == 0){

             line(  b.getEdgeVertexA(0).x*img.width, b.getEdgeVertexA(0).y*img.height, 0, 0   );
             println("drew to 0,0");
           }

           if (b.getEdgeVertexA(m).y == 0 && b.getEdgeVertexB(b.getEdgeNb()).x == 0){

             line(  b.getEdgeVertexA(m).x*img.width, b.getEdgeVertexA(m ).y*img.height, 0, 0   );
             println("drew to 0,0");
           }
           */
           ////////////

        }

        //Adding objects to the rings ArrayList
        rings.add(new Ring(String.valueOf(rings.size()+1), (int) i, (double) b.x*100, (double) b.y*100));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I know I know my code does not include any code to draw these edges, so they are not really missing, but I am kind of lost as to where to start to properly draw these.

I have thought about:

- checking if any coordinate of a vertex that constitutes the blob is equal to 0 (min width or height) or 1 (max width or height)
- drawing a strait line from the blob extremities to the top left corner of the sketch if for example the blob is overlapping that corner
- many other conditions, but so many I am confused...

Anyone have an idea of how to order conditions, or how to approach the problem...
Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine stumbled upon a smart solution to this problem, which is to increase the size of the original image by one pixel on each side, and to make these pixels black.
So if the image was 100x100px, it would then be 102x102px. We add black pixels in our case, but I think the best way to do this would be to calculate the cutoff color that determines whether to draw a blob or not, and to assign these new border pixels a color slightly or just below/above that (depending on you needs).

The code is mostly the same as in my original question, except the part where we import and modify the image:

```
PImage ref;
PImage output;
String filename = "maptest2.jpg";

// // //

//Here I skip some parts that are unchanged

// // //

void setup() {

  size(480, 360, P3D);
  surface.setResizable(true);

  ref = loadImage(filename);
  
  // create a copy of reference image with a black border
  output = createImage(ref.width+2, ref.height+2, RGB);
  
  for(int i=0; i < output.pixels.length; i++){
    output.pixels[i] = color(0);
  }
  
  output.updatePixels();
  output.set(1, 1, ref);
  
  surface.setSize(output.width, output.height);

  cam = new PeasyCam(this, output.width, output.height, 0, 1500);
```

The resulting SVG output, with the desired outer borders:

[image]

This is not the solution I was expecting when I asked this question, but it works pretty well. It certainly could be perfected a bit, but I tested it on a bunch of other height maps I'm working with and the results are consistently satisfying.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A method I often use in processing to constrain my drawing to within the bounds of the window is the min and max functions. It reduces the number of inequality if statements I used to write.

Try this in your loop, I haven't tested it so I hope it gives you the desired output, but it should just draw the edges along the edge of your image.

```
          eA = b.getEdgeVertexA(m);
          eB = b.getEdgeVertexB(m);

          //This part draws the blobs.
        if (eA !=null && eB !=null){
          float x1 = eA.x*img.width;
          float y1 = eA.y*img.height;
          float x2 = eB.x*img.width;
          float y2 = eB.y*img.height;

          x1 = min(max(0,x1),WIDTH);
          y1 = min(max(0,y1),HEIGHT);
          x2 = min(max(0,x2),WIDTH);
          y2 = min(max(0,y2),HEIGHT);


          line(x1, y1, x2, y2);

           println("eA.x: " + eA.x + " x1: " + x1);
           println("eA.y: " + eA.y + " y1: " + y1);
           println("eB.x: " + eB.x + " x2: " + x2);
           println("eB.y: " + eB.y + " y2: " + y2);
           println();
         }
```

The logic is as follows: `min(max(0,x1),WIDTH)`

First we find `max(0,x1)` so we are making sure x1 is greater than 0, if it is negative set it to 0.

Then we take the result of the previous operation and do the following `min(result,WIDTH)` so are trying to find the minimum number between the two, we know that the result is >= 0, and the WIDTH of the window is >= 1, so if the number is bigger than the width of the window, constrain it to the width.

We end up with a number that is between `0` and `WIDTH`, if the original value was already within those constraints it is unmodified. This should draw any edges that would be drawn on the outside of the window along the edges. Give it a try and let me know if it works!

Comment: I tried the code as is and it did not work. I will modify it a bit and try it again but I think its not really what I need. From what I understand, your code checks if a blob goes over the edge of the sketch, but since I start with a height map image file, the boundaries are the image, and the blobs go over the edge only in imagination. So really, the code should check if a blob is in complete (not closed), and then close it along the edge of he sketch.